# Show alternately text and image at the center

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is piece of my code:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Visibility="Collapsed" Stretch="None" Name="BImage" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 100 10 10">
    </Image>
    <TextBlock Margin="10 0 10 0" Name="InnerContent" FontSize="45"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" "/>
```

What I would like to achieve is to show BImage and InnerContent alternately but text should be always in the center of the image space so that when image is replaced by text, text is in the middle of the space of the image.

And when this is done I would like to add another TextBlock called errorTextBlock and it should be always visible just below BImage or InnerContent according to which one is visible right now.

I hope that it's clear

Comment: Put both controls in a Grid and set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to `Center` for both.

Comment: use a Grid with both H and V Alignment with Center

Comment: @Clemens is right, but I also edited my question

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help.

```
public System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();        

_timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
_timer.Start();

int second = 0;  // a local variable to keep tab on alternate visibility of elements per second in _timer_Tick

void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  second++;
  if((second % 2) == 0) 
  {
    InnerContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    BImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  }
  else
  {
    BImage.Visibility = System.Windows.VisibilityHidden;
    InnerContent.Visibilty = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```